# Why does my tkinter box never close and do not print on my terminal

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def ticks():

    tickers = str(my_box.get())

init()

root = Tk()
root.title('ticker')
#root.iconbitmap('')
root.geometry("400x400")

my_label = Label(root, text = "Enter the ticker")
my_label.pack(pady = 20)

my_box = Entry(root)
my_box.pack(pady = 10)

my_button = Button(root, text = "Validate", command = ticks)
my_button.pack(pady = 20)

answer = Label(root, text='')
answer.pack(pady = 20)


root.mainloop()

print(tickers)
```

Dear All,

it seem that my ticker Box never close when I push the button validate.

Therefore, it is not printing the ticker I enter.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Sincerely,`enter code here`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you want to know. want to print the 'tickers' when you push the button? or type the text and then print the 'tickers' after close the tkinter?

Supposed at second case,

```
tickers = ''

def get_ticks():
    global tickers
    tickers = str(my_box.get())

root = Tk()
root.title('ticker')
root.geometry("400x400")

my_label = Label(root, text = "Enter the ticker")
my_label.pack(pady = 20)

my_box = Entry(root)
my_box.pack(pady = 10)

my_button = Button(root, text = "Validate", command = get_ticks)
my_button.pack(pady = 20)

answer = Label(root, text='')
answer.pack(pady = 20)


root.mainloop()

print(tickers)
```

You have to check global variable in button command

Comment: Dear Chansub,

your code works perfectly and i would like to thank you for your help

how can i close the window when i push the validate button ?

Many thanks

Comment: @Unconnuanonyme use `root.destroy()`